# How do I directly scan from Canon Pixma MX925 to Evernote?

Tags: cloud, evernote, canon-pixma

I just got a Pixma MX925 and want to set up scanning directly to Evernote.

It is adverterised that the printer can scan to the cloud (Dropbox, Evernote ...) but I can find the Pixma Cloud Link or any other set up option for this.
Firmware is 2.01.

Comment: I believe you need the Evernote software, which then integrates directly with your scanner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing two different things:

Cloud Link allows you to print your items from anywhere - [info](http://www.canon.com.au/For-You/Printers/PIXMA-Connectivity/Cloud-Link)

Scannignt o evernote and dropbox is feature of integration between the printer and the software - look [here](http://evernote.com/partner/canon/)

Just:
Evernote works great with your Canon scanner! With Evernote, all of your scanned documents will be accessible from any computer or phone you use. If you don't already have an Evernote account, then download Evernote and follow the 4 simple steps below.

Download and install Evernote

Launch Evernote and click the link to create an account

Sign into Evernote on the desktop

Start scanning!

Comment: I just would be more convenient to send the document directly to an Evernote email address without a PC. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 2):

Basically Canon are mis-selling their mx925, I had exactly the same problem. They advertise it as being able to 'Scan to Cloud' but in reality it is no such thing.

I sent mine back as I really wanted a MFP with scan to cloud functionality, being able to scan without having to boot up a PC or Mac.

You might be able to scan via mobile app which might be better.

Comment: Did you fix a MFP that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

I just bought a MX922 (seems to be the US version of MX925) and can confirm that it doesn't support scanning to cloud.

This Canon website shows that its considered an old model that even though it has the PIXMA Cloud Link logo doesn't support the new version of Pixma cloud

http://www.canon-europe.com/printers/inkjet/pixma/cloud-printing/

Super annoying if you ask me